# Kotlin - What is the point of private variables inside private companion objects?

Tags: class, kotlin, static, private

Suppose I have the class

```
class Foo {
    private companion object {
        private val hello = "world"
    }
}
```

Is there any point in making `Foo.hello` private if the companion object is already private?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a practical difference: `hello` can be accessed anywhere inside `Foo`, but nowhere outside it, regardless of whether it's private or not.

However, you might find making it private makes the situation clearer, especially if the companion object is big.  You might find it clarifies the intent.  And it ensures that `hello` can't be accessed outside, even if the companion object is later changed to be non-private.  So there are slight differences in style.